# Undefined Method error in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

```ruby
require "test/unit/assertions"
include Test::Unit::Assertions

def key_for_min_value(hash)
  arr = Array.new
  arr = hash.min_by{ |key,value| value}
  if arr[0]==nil
  return nil
  else return arr[0]
  end
end


assert_equal key_for_min_value({"k" => 2, "h" => 3, "j" => 1}), "j"
assert_equal key_for_min_value({"o" => 0, "z" => -2, "j" => 1}), "z"
assert_equal key_for_min_value({}), nil
```

This code is returning the following error.Why?

test1.rb:7:in `key_for_min_value': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test1.rb:13:in `'

Comment: because you are trying to call `[]` on `nil`. that is because you assign `arr` twice, in your last assertion it becomes `nil`.

Comment: please specify clearly, unable to understand your comment

Answer (score -1):

when arr = nil in your third test, you can't call arr[0], because nil doesn't have a [] method. Your check on line 13 should instead be `if arr == nil`.